# Zoom App OAuth Scope doesn't appear in scope options

Tags: zoom-sdk

I am currently trying to build an app for zoom, and need the Zoom App scope from OAuth, but the option isn't appearing for me. Any possible reason why?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your zoom app without the OAuth layer if you don't require users to login. Say its just a widget that allows users to add augmented reality backgrounds.

I don't think there is an OAuth scope.